# Find the missing country

Tags: knowledge, geography

Below is a list of ten countries, with one missing. Find one attribute (for example, the population) of each country, so that if you take the first number or first letter of each country’s attribute, in the order shown, it forms a familiar ten-character number, word or phrase. What is the one attribute, and what is the missing country? If more than one country could qualify, then list the country with the largest population, as of August 2019.

```
Ukraine
Spain
Honduras
Albania
Mauritania
South Korea
Mauritania
?
Bulgaria
Canada
```

Answer (score 13):

The attribute is

> the currencies of those countries: **H**ryvnia, **E**uro, **L**empira, **L**ek, **O**uguiya, **W**on, **O**uguiya, ?, **L**ev, **D**ollar.

And the missing country is

> India, which uses the **R**upee, completing the phrase "Hello world".

Comment: Pakistan uses the pakistan rupee, which may also be a valid answer (if not for the size tiebreaker)

Comment: Indonesia, the Maldives, Mauritius, Nepal, Seychelles, and Sri Lanka use rupees too, but India has the largest population.

Comment: Yes, there are other options; Russia would also work, but India is clearly the largest country (by population) that fits this property.

Comment: @Duck Indonesia uses Rupiah btw, and it's not similar to Rupee :D

Comment: Oh, my bad... It still starts with 'r' though...

Comment: Rupee is incorrect. There is a larger-populated country with an R currency.

Comment: Would the answer then be Chinese Renminbi?

Comment: @FlanMan Is it Russia and Rouble?

Comment: @projectilemotion "Would the answer then be Chinese Renminbi?" Yes, China is the most populous country with an R currency (and the most populous country, currently).